# Firebase fuction returning "Response is not valid JSON object."

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to send emails from a `firebase` function that I call from my `vue` app. My firebase function looks like:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin")
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

admin.initializeApp()


//google account credentials used to send email
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: 'xxxxx@gmail.com',
        pass: 'xxxxxxxxxx'
    }
});


exports.sendMail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    const mailOptions = {
        from: `•••••••••@gmail.com`,
        to: req.body.email,
        subject: 'contact form message',
        html: `<h1>Order Confirmation</h1>
                            <p>
                               <b>Email: </b>"hello<br>
                            </p>`
    };


    return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, data) => {
        console.log("here")
        if (error) {
            return res.send({"data": error.toString()});
        }
        data = JSON.stringify(data)
        return res.send({"data": `Sent! ${data}`});
    });

});
```

I removed the user and pass values here. They have the correct value in my code. The `vue` method I use to call this function looks like:

```
sendEmail(){
        let sendMail = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('sendMail');
        sendMail(
            {
                email: 'xx@xx.xx.xx'
            }
        ).then(
            result => {
                console.log(result.data)
            }
        )
    }
```

When this function is called I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Response is not valid JSON object.
at new e (index.cjs.js:58)
at t.<anonymous> (index.cjs.js:543)
at u (tslib.es6.js:100)
at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:81)
at s (tslib.es6.js:71)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must a return a valid `JSON` result like this:

`return res.status(200).json({});`

Here the `JSON is` `{}` but it could be for instance something like `{"status": "success}`.

Comment: I changed both the error and the success to `return res.status(200).json({});` and I get  `error: Response is missing data field.

Comment: Thus the error still comes from what interprets the response. And it clearly says that it's waiting for a field data in the response, something like return res.status(200).json({data: "mydata"});

Answer (score 15):

Just incase this helps anyone Googling the issue, I got the "Response is not valid JSON object." error because I didn't specify the correct region in my client and my function wasn't hosted in the default us region. I'm writing a react-native firebase app so I had to change:

```
const result = await firebase.app().functions().httpsCallable("nameGoesHere");
```

To:

```
const result = await firebase.app().functions("europe-west1").httpsCallable("nameGoesHere");
```

Comment: That was exactly my problem : I had an httpsCallable function that was returning "Response is not valid JSON object." because I did not set the region.
Also, I was calling `firebase.function()` instead of `firebase.app().functions("region")` which didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

The issue might be with the handler. You're using `functions().httpsCallable('your_name')` but the handle of the functions is `onRequest`. According to the documentation, there should be `onCall` function handler.

Something like:
`exports.sendMail = functions.https.onCall((data) => { your_code_here });`

Docs - https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell if this is the case from the code, but this always happens to me when I export a function in one file and then forget to include it in the index file.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this because I forgot to connect the emulator:

```
import { connectFunctionsEmulator, getFunctions } from 'firebase/functions'

...
const functions = getFunctions(app)
connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, '127.0.0.1', 5001)
```

Note for me using 'localhost' caused an internal error

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me that I changed the function name from `name1` to `name2` and in my function calling `name1` the response was always `"Response is not valid JSON object."`

*It happened to me in Flutter*