# Error: Response is not valid JSON object error wih valid JSON object

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

i just wanted to do get firestore data from firebase with functions. Like regular rest api.

So i created functions/index.js like this:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();
const geolib = require('geolib');


exports.rangeCalculators = functions.region('europe-west3').https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const list = []
    const { latitude, longitude } = request.body.userlocation
    db.collection("Zones").get().then((x) => {
        x.docs.forEach(y => {
            if (geolib.getDistance(
                { latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude },
                { latitude: y.data().coordinates.latitude, longitude: y.data().coordinates.longitude }, 1) < 2000) {
                list.push(y.data())
            }
        });
    }).then(() => {
        console.log(list)
        return response.json({list})
    })
});
```

my react native App.js like this:

```
import functions from '@react-native-firebase/functions';

export default function App() {

  const [userRegion, setUserRegion] = useState({})
  const [locs, setLocations] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(userRegion)
    console.log(locs)
    const func = functions().httpsCallable('rangeCalculators');
    func({ userlocation: userRegion }).then((res) => {
      console.log(JSON.parse(res.data))
    }).catch(e => console.log(e))
  }, [userRegion])

  return (...)}
```

then in metro console it says:

[Error: Response is not valid JSON object.]

i cant even see "res" value.

but when i try with postman it returns normal
[image]
when i try with postman i can see logs in firebase function console

but when i try with application theres no logs in console. i think it cant reach to function

how can i solve that issue?

what i tried:
i tried to change in App.js functions region but theres no references for that.

do i need to add region to app.js?

Comment: can you refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61204230/15774176 is ithelpful?